# Save .sav file on jupyter notebook

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook

I want to save a model trained with joblib library on jupyter into a file with extension .sav . But I am getting an error below when opening the file.

My code:

```
modelname = ModelPath + "/" + str(ModelName) + '_' + str(TrainValRatio) + ".sav"
joblib.dump(model, modelname)
```

My error:

```
1 Error! C:\Users\ASUS\AnimalACCML\AlphaTest_Johnwilliams_09202022\Models\ExtraTreesClassifier_0.2.sav is not UTF-8 encoded
2 Saving disabled.
3 See Console for more details.
```

Please help me to fix this error.